# How does one find the targets that a particular Makefile exposes

Tags: build, makefile

Many a time, I would do the standard `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` when compiling a package.

However, there are times when  I see a package being built with optional `make` parameters that are specific to that package.

Is there a easy way to list the bundled targets other than going through the Makefile source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general statement, no.

If there are meaningful variables the project should call them out specifically.

The bash (and probably zsh) tab completion support does attempt to get available make targets (with varying degrees of success) if that is of help though.

Comment: That's what I suspected ('no'), but wanted to check.  How can one enable Bash completions for make targets?

Comment: @HanSooloo It is on by default on my debian machine (part of the bash-completion package) but doesn't seem to exist on my CentOS 5 machine. Beyond that, unfortunately, I can't really say.